# Read a file in Java in the same folder of the runtime jar

Tags: java, maven, configuration

I have a Maven Java application which accesses an XML configuration file. This configuration file should be placed in the same folder of the application jar so that any configuration would easily "follow" the application.

I use the following piece of code to get the jar's absolute path

```
String path = Runner.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
```

Running it in debug mode returns the following path

```
/C:/Users/user/git/project/project/target/classes/
```

So the jar is run (in debug mode) from the `target/classes` folder thus the XML config file should be placed in that folder.

The problem is that whenever I rebuild the project the `target` folder gets overwritten and the config file deleted.

Is there any way to solve this problem, which affects only the development phase?
I was thinking about telling Maven to not delete the config file in some way, but I don't know how.

Thank you in advance

Best regards,

Giulio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achived using maven out of the box. Simply put the XML file in src/main/resources/, during the build it will be copied into target/classes

```
mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=sub.optimal.example -DartifactId=superapp
cd superapp/
mkdir src/main/resources
touch src/main/resources/example.xml
mvn package
ls target/classes/*.xml
```

cheers

Comment: Ho @SubOptimal. Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to do this directly into the project, maybe configuring a Maven plugin into the pom.xml?
I wouldn't like to use Maven from the outside of Eclipse

Comment: @Suboptimal, target/classes is not "the same folder of the application jar"

Comment: @gvdm you don't need to configure something. Create a directory src/main/resources/ and store the files there. The files will be copied to target/classes/.

Comment: @Andres I agree. Maybe I misread the question from gvdm. I tought he has only problems during the debug "So the jar is run (in debug mode) from the target/classes folder thus the XML config file should be placed in that folder."

Comment: Ok, maybe I misread it. If the objective is to copy the file on target/classes, your answer is correct.